# Regex Match As Much As Possible Until The Next Match

Tags: regex, pcre

I have a text that comprises codes and texts for each code and it follows a certain pattern. I am trying to get the code and the text of each code by grouping each in a pattern, however, my pattern is matching the and returning 1 match and get the first code in one group and the rest of the whole text as the second group. What I am trying to achieve is for my second group to match as much as possible until it sees that the pattern has been repeated. I am using [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Ue30gq/2) to fiddle with the pattern and see what I can work with, several options did not yield my results.

In my pattern I specified that the code should be `([A-Z0-9]{1,6})`, I also tried specifying the codes that I will be using as follows `(ADD|DELETE)` but it still seems to match once.

Can this be actually done or is my pattern obscure and not valid for my case? The pattern and text I am working on are included in the above link.

Comment: Please consider adding some sample inputs and the outputs you want the code to produce

Comment: Remove `\/`: https://regex101.com/r/Ue30gq/3. Or, use `\/([A-Z0-9]{1,6})\/([^\/]+)`. Check https://regex101.com/r/Ue30gq/4

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/Ue30gq/5

Comment: People downvote the question and try to close it because they expect simple statements: *I'm doing X I get Y but I need Z. What should I do?*

Comment: Here you go. Let me know if yor are looking for something else. If yes, then some examples would help me understand the scenario. Regex per what I understood: `\/(?:\w)+\/` Example: https://regex101.com/r/Ue30gq/6

Comment: I see your example and came up with scenario 2. Use whatever you need. Regex2: `(\/(?:[A-z0-9]+)\/)(?:(?>(?!(?1))[\s\S])+)` Example: https://regex101.com/r/Ue30gq/7

Comment: @Deep your second pattern matches what I am looking for which is each combination of code and text consists of 1 match and I get the code and text alone in groups. However, I do not know of the atomic group construct, I will look into it to understand what it does.

Comment: If my answer worked for you, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use

```
(?s)\/([A-Za-z0-9]{1,6})\/((?:(?!\/[A-Za-z0-9]{1,6}\/).)*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/s51Xux/2).

A bit shorter version is possible since in PCRE you may recurse capturing group patterns with regex subroutines. The `\/([A-Za-z0-9]{1,6})\/` part can be wrapped with its own capturing group and then, instead of repeating the pattern, you may use `(?1)`:

```
(?s)(\/([A-Za-z0-9]{1,6})\/)((?:(?!(?1)).)*)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/s51Xux/3). Note the presence of the "technical" group #1, it will always be present in the results of the match(es).

However, if you prefer efficiency I'd rather recommend an unroll-the-loop version of the same regex:

```
\/([A-Za-z0-9]{1,6})\/([^\/]*(?:\/(?![A-Za-z0-9]{1,6}\/)[^\/]*)*)
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/s51Xux/4)

The `(?s)` inline DOTALL modifier that allows `.` match any chars including line break chars is necessary only with the first two patterns, as the third one does not contain, does not rely on a dot pattern, but rather on a negated character class, `[^\/]`. It matches any char but `/`, including line break chars.

**Pattern details**

- `(?s)` - a DOTALL inline modifier
- `\/([A-Za-z0-9]{1,6})\/` - `/`, (Group 1) 1 to 6 alphanumeric chars, `/`
- `((?:(?!\/[A-Za-z0-9]{1,6}\/).)*)` - (Group 2) any char (`.`), 0 or more repetitions (`*`), that does not start a `/[A-Za-z0-9]{1,6}/` matching substring
- `(?1)` - in the second regex version, it is just the same as `\/[A-Za-z0-9]{1,6}\/`
- `[^\/]*(?:\/(?![A-Za-z0-9]{1,6}\/)[^\/]*)*` = `(?:(?!\/[A-Za-z0-9]{1,6}\/).)*` - any 0+ chars other than `/` (`[^\/]*`) and then 0 or more repetitions of `/` not followed with a `[A-Za-z0-9]{1,6}\/` matching substring, and 0+ chars other than `/`.